# Adding date to file name when sending email

Tags: linux, shell-script, date

I want to add current date to the file name. when sending an email with attachment.

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear

now=`date +"%m_%d_%Y"`

mutt -s "Reports $now" someone@gmail.com -a /path/Reports.xlsx < /path/mailmessage.txt
```

However, I want the current date with filename instead in email subject. As the file is modified daily and sent out through email.

eg: Reports_08032017.xlsx when received in email.

Is it possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary copy with desired filename which you can delete after sending the mail.

```
NOW=$(date +'%m_%d_%Y')
TMPCOPY="/tmp/Reports_$NOW.xlsx"

cp "/path/Reports.xlsx" "$TMPCOPY"
mutt -s "Reports $NOW" someone@gmail.com -a "$TMPCOPY" < /path/mailmessage.txt

rm "$TMPCOPY"
```

Comment: Thanks, should I create a /tmp/ folder for TMPCOPY?

Comment: You can use any folder you prefer to. `/tmp` is for storing temporary files and it should exist on basically any linux system.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to do when the file is created but you can also change the name of it like this:

```
today=$(date +%m-%d-%Y)
file="/path/Reports.xlsx"
nfile="/path/Reports-$today.xlsx"
mv $file $nfile
```